I want to use a SpeedoMeter widget with compose UI for my android project but i can't figure out how to add it
I am using the following repository as a reference: https://github.com/anastr/Speedometer/tree/master
I have a native Android project and have added the dependencies mentioned in the repository to my Gradle file.
This is my build.gradle.kts app module level:
dependencies {
    implementation("com.github.anastr:speedometer-android:1.0.0-ALPHA02")
}

and this is my settings.gradle.kts:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

However, I am unsure how to actually use it to customize the speedometer. I am very new to Android development, and I haven’t used external libraries before, so I'm not sure where I might be going wrong.
In the repository it has written that "to use it, just call SpeedView composable" So, I created a new Kotlin file and tried to call SpeedView, but I get an error: "Expecting top-level declaration."
after that I tried this import statement: "import com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView" but it gave an "unresolved reference" error.
import com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView


SpeedView(
modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp),
speed = 50f,
)

Now, I’m not sure what to do.
and please be vey kind to me, I'm a bit stupid at following instruction :(

Ignore SpeedView() for the moment. Use Compose to set up the rest of your screen, whether by following the documentation or books or training. Then, once you have more of your screen established and you have greater comfort with implementing and using composable functions, it will be easier for you to see where you can add SpeedView(). Your lines of code in the question may be fine, but they need to be part of some larger composable.
